# Drupal 8: Node preview when using Page Manager

Tags: 8

I am using the Page Manager module in D8 to show the full node view pages. Drupal also provides a button to preview the content when creating/editing it. Is there a possibility to actually preview the page using the page manager layout?

Thanks for the answers!

Vasi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ouf the box because page_manager is about *routes*, and node preview is a completely different route than viewing a node.

Something like Display suite and probably also Panelizer (never really used it myself) whould probably work there though.

That said, it should be possible to build something too with Page Manager too by creating a second page (with a duplicated page variant(s) that you need to keep in sync somehow) that overides the preview route, but you also need to somehow write a context provider that loads the node based on the passed tempstore argument and also a write a block that replicates the UI elements for selecting the view mode and going back to edit

Comment: Thanks for the reply Berdir! Yeah, I already thought about this solution (good point with the need to replicate the UI elements for selecting the view mode and go back to edit), was thinking that maybe there is an easier option here. I suppose not...